Wired connection stops internet connection from wifi after installing Kubuntu 24.04
This is the thing, I used to have both connections at once, the wired and the wifi. I use the wired connection to communicate with other computers on my local network and I use the wifi to access internet. After a fresh installation of Kubuntu 24.04 I am facing this problem: if I connect the wired connection I lose my internet connection via wifi, and I need these two connections working at the same time.
Any hint on how to solve this?


Take a look at the answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370866/i-cant-use-wifi-and-ethernet-at-the-same-time and https://superuser.com/questions/1417104/connect-to-both-wifi-and-ethernet-simultaneously-in-ubuntu-16-04
